# Will I get a Promise once use context.done()?

Tags: azure-functions

I've followed all guidelines from MS writing Azure Function. Somehow have to use `.done()` else client (Postman) won't see any returns:

```
module.exports = async function(context)
{
  ...
  const result = await aPromise().catch((bad)=>
    {
    context.res = {status: 401, body: "bad"};
    context.done();  // needed so client can get the above res
    });
}
```

Does it mean the return is not a `Promise`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function is **synchronous** it doesn't return a **Promise**, so you must pass the `context` object, as calling **context.done**  is required for correct use.

// You should include context, other arguments are optional

```
module.exports = function(context, yourTrigger, yourInput) {
    // your function code
    context.done();
};
```

[image]

If your function is [`async function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). You don’t need to call the **context.text.** While your async function declaration of the Functions runtime, you do not need to explicitly call the [`context.done`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#contextdone-method) callback to signal that your function has been completed.

It is applicable from function version `2.x`. If you are using function version `1.x` you need to call the context.done callback.

```
module.exports = async function (context) {
    context.log(‘your log');
};
```

[image]

**Note:**

Explicitly calling `done` is unnecessary when writing an **async function** the `done` callback is called implicitly.

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#exporting-a-function)  for more information